# How to pass additional data to the Catch task when Lambda Invoke fails with Error?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have this lambda function written in nodejs:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    throw new CustomError('Custom error with data!', {
        propA: 'A',
        propB: 'B',
    });
};

class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(message, data) {
        super(message);
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        this.data = data; // I have declared a new field which contains some useful data for handling error in other lambda function.
    }
}
```

I've made a state machine with this lambda function as a first task and added a catcher function for this task. When I launched a new execution, I saw the following output from the Lambda Invoke task (input to the Catch task was the same):

```
{
  "Error": "CustomError",
  "Cause": "{\"errorType\":\"CustomError\",\"errorMessage\":\"Custom error with data!\",\"trace\":[\"CustomError: Cannot list objects\",\"    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:5:11)\",\"    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:74:25)\"]}"
}
```

As you can see, there is no `data` field in the Catch input. I would like to pass `data` object of the `CustomError` to the Catch task. Is this possible? Are there any other ways how to pass additional error data to the Catch task? Appreciate any help.

State machine JSON:

```
{
  "StartAt": "SomeJob",
  "States": {
    "SomeJob": {
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "HandleErrorTask"
        }
      ],
      "End": true,
      "Type": "Task",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "...",
        "Payload.$": "$"
      }
    },
    "HandleErrorTask": {
      "End": true,
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "...",
        "Payload.$": "$"
      }
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 300
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) handles [Function Errors in node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-exceptions.html), I believe the only way you can return custom data in this scenario is in the type and message for your node.js Error. [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) interacts with Lambda using the [Invoke API Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html), so there's nothing special happening or possible with Step Functions.

That said, I can think of a couple things which might help.

First, if the data you need in your `HandleErorrTask` is available in the input to the `SomeJob` task, you can use the `ResultPath` property in your Catcher. I've included an updated example below and you can [read more about fallback states in the docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-fallback-states). In this case, the `HandleErrorTask` will receive the input that `SomeJob` received augmented with the error information.

```
{
  "StartAt": "SomeJob",
  "States": {
    "SomeJob": {
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "HandleErrorTask",
          "ResultsPath": "$.errordata"
        }
      ],
      "End": true,
      "Type": "Task",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "...",
        "Payload.$": "$"
      }
    },
    "HandleErrorTask": {
      "End": true,
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "...",
        "Payload.$": "$"
      }
    }
  },
  "TimeoutSeconds": 300
}
```

Another option if you need to return specific data that is only available or generated in your function would be to not raise this as an error in your code. Instead, have your Lambda Function return successfully but with a field to indicate the logical failure that you could then use a [Choice State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) to direct exceptional responses to your `HandleErrorTask` state.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sad to know that. Input does not include the information I need to pass to the Catcher task. Hoping that this ability will be implemented. Choise is also not a good option for my case, because I have about 10-20 lambdas which can throw errors and I don't really want to write 10-20 additional Choices for it, it might increase state machine cost per execution. I think I will serialize an object into ErrorMessage and deserialize it on Catcher side.